# windows 7 emergency restore CD

Tags: windows, restore, system-restore

I recently upgraded from XP to Windows 7.  Unfortunately, I haven't really finished.  I got my System up and working pretty good and backups running using Windows 7 backup.  But I did not create an emergency repair disk.  Well the drive and/or motherboard crapped out tonight.  My system is 4 years old and I've been looking to get a new one.  I guess it's time...

My issue is that I will now want to restore my files and such to a new system.  Will I need the emergency restore CD to access the backups (on 300GB eSATA external hard drive)?  If so how can I make one?  I have a legal copy of Windows 7 Home Premium, but it was registered to the system that is dead.  Can I use it to put on a new OS image on the new system long enough to create the restore CD?  How can I migrate the license from the dead system to the new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on how you did the backup.  You did either a backup or a "system image".

If you did a backup, you can browse the actual backup (right click and say open) file in your new installation of Windows, or you can quite possibly restore them using the Restore function.

If you did a system image, you can use the install disc to restore that, I believe.  I believe that also functions as a recovery disc.

As to getting a new installation of windows on your new system, I think you can restore the image or backup file from that stage, and you probably won't need to activate the copy of Windows.  Eventually, you will, but I doubt you'll have much trouble.  Even if you got an "OEM" (system builder version, not one tied to a specific brand like Dell) I'm sure MS will let you activate it with a phone call...instructions will be provided if your system fails activation.

Comment: If it's not OEM just call IF there are any issues

Comment: Would there be any issues because the old system is of completely different hardware than the new?  I would expect Windows7 might not like to boot with the image of an old system applied to the new.

Comment: Answer: http://superuser.com/questions/50275/windows7-full-system-backup-bare-metal-restore-maybe-diff-specs